# Int[] to Matrix Java

Tags: java

How do I convert a int[] to a matrix?

Let's say I want to make 6x6 matrix and I have an int[] array with 36 elements.
So the 00 entry is the 0th element of the array, 01: 1 element, 02:, 2nd element and so forth.

Comment: If you want to do linear algebra on this matrix, check out the JAMA library: http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about:

```
int[] ints = new int[36];
// fill with values
int[][] matrix = new int[6][6];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    matrix[i / 6][i % 6] = ints[i];
}
```

To help you understand why this works, add the following inside the loop:

```
System.out.println("i = " + i + "; i / 6 = " + (i / 6) + "; i % 6 = " + (i % 6) + ";");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    matrix[i][j] = vector[i * 6 + j];
```